# Readable boot messages on Plymouth

Tags: ubuntu, plymouth

I'm designing a Plymouth theme and I want to display boot messages. I do it using `Plymouth.SetUpdateStatusFunction()` by simply dumping the message into the callback argument.

The problem is, instead of (relatively) friendly messages like those usually seen on verbose Debian and derivatives boot that kinda look like these

```
Starting some service....
[OK] Some service started.
Starting some other service....
[OK] Some other service started.
```

I just get these

```
some.service
some-other.service
volume-uuid.mount
```

How do you get it to output messages like the default theme?